# Are DependencyProperties automatically reset when their parent is detached?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Let's assume the following case:

You have a `UserControl` with a DependencyProperty that I call `ID` for this example.

- If `ID` is set, the user control registers with some `IObservable` and will be informed whenever the `IObservable` changes.
- If the `ID` is changed, the user control unregisters from the first `IObservable` and registers with a second `IObservable`.
- If the `ID` is reset (i.e. set to `null`), the user control unregisters without re-registering.

Let's now assume that you open a Window that contains this user control. You then set `ID` to something non-`null`. Now you close the Window.

**Main Question:** Will `ID` be reset to `null` automatically when closing the window (and thereby detaching the child user control)? If yes, what part of WPF is responsible for that? (Will the `DataContext` of the user control be reset and does this cause `ID` to be reset to its default value?)

---

Reason for asking this question: If it is not guaranteed that `ID` will be reset to `null` automatically, I have to find a way to detect the detachment of the user control and unregister from the currently registered `IObservable` "manually".

Comment: I don't think so it will be set to `null` automatically. It won't be that hard to try it yourself. Is it?

Comment: I did try it and it was actually reset each time so far. However, this is no prove that it will be reset in every case. (My component is quite critical and I'm not willing to rely on just a few random tests for this.) That's why I'm looking for a definite answer, preferably with a short explanation for *why* it is reset.

Comment: From what I know, the dependencyProperty will retain reference to the closest dependencyObject if what you bind it to is not a dependencyProperty more info is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/02/04/finding-memory-leaks-in-wpf-based-applications.aspx). (But that is not always the case). HTH

Comment: Do not rely on any internal behaviour in WPF. Just attach a handler for the control's `Unloaded` event and perform all necessary cleanup.